# cvent soap api error (php)

Tags: php, api, soap

I'm trying to use php to get access to the Cvent soap API to display a list of upcoming events. I found this: https://github.com/gcanivet/php-cvent

I'm getting "INVALID_CVENT_HEADER_VALUE" when it comes to this function:

```
public function SearchByFilter($objecttype, $type, $filters){   
    $response = $this->client->Search((object) array('ObjectType' => $objecttype, 'CvSearchObject' => (object) array('SearchType' => $type, 'Filter' => $filters)));
    return $response;
}
```

I've echoed out what's being sent to that function:

```
$objecttype = 'Event';
$type = 'AndSearch';
$filters = 

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field] => EventStartDate
            [Operator] => Greater than
            [Value] => 2016-11-28T00:00:00
        )

)
```

All I've done is save the file, add my credentials and attempted to echo out $events

```
$account    = /* my account */
$username   = /* my username */
$password   = /* my password */

require('/templates/home/assets/CventClient.class.php');
$cc = new CventClient();
$cc->Login($account,$username,$password);
$events = $cc->GetUpcomingEvents();
```

I've found this documentation https://custom.cvent.com/5A44061C587B4DF999B70EC98DCA9A84/files/eb1d01535a124863a290b36fa4cd8bd3.pdf but I'm not sure what's wrong, or why it's not working. I have had no experience with SOAP whatsoever. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned result when you `var_dump($event)` is the keys of the event. To get the title of the event you have to get the `eventId`.

```
 `require('/templates/home/assets/CventClient.class.php');

 $cc = new CventClient();

 $cc->Login($account,$username,$password);

 $events = $cc->GetUpcomingEvents();

  foreach($events as $event)
    {
    $response = $cc->GetEventById($event);
    //This retrieves the title of all events
     $eventsTitle = $response->EventTitle;

     var_dump($eventsTitle );
   }`
```